# Swashbuckle Swagger UI OpenID Connect Support

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

According to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/, Swagger UI now has support for OpenID Connect.  Does anyone know or have a sample project that explains how to configure an Asp.net Core Web API project using Swashbuckle or NSwag using OpenID Connect?

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, if you want to use the OpenID Connect in swagger UI, you should install the Swashbuckle which is bundled Swagger UI to the v. 3.38.0 later version.

Then I you could use it like below:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    var apiinfo = new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "theta-CandidateAPI",
        Version = "v1",
        Description = "Candidate API for thetalentbot",
        Contact = new OpenApiContact
        { Name = "thetalentbot", Url = new Uri("https://thetalentbot.com/developers/contact") },
            License = new OpenApiLicense()
            {
                Name = "Commercial",
                Url = new Uri("https://thetalentbot.com/developers/license")
             }
        };

        OpenApiSecurityScheme securityDefinition = new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
        {
            Name = "Bearer",
            BearerFormat = "JWT",
            Scheme = "bearer",
            Description = "Specify the authorization token.",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        };

        OpenApiSecurityRequirement securityRequirements = new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
        {
            {securityScheme, new string[] { }},
        };

        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", apiinfo);
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("jwt_auth", securityDefinition);
        // Make sure swagger UI requires a Bearer token to be specified
        options.AddSecurityRequirement(securityRequirements);               
});
```

If you want to use OpenID Connect Discovery, you could add below codes in it,.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    //... omitted for brevity
    //baseAccountsUrl is "https://localhost:5401"

    c.AddSecurityDefinition("AccountsOpenID", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OpenIdConnect,
        OpenIdConnectUrl = new Uri($"{baseAccountsUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration")
    });
}
```

Comment: Where does the `securityScheme` variable come from in the requirements definition?

Comment: Here's the declaration for securityScheme:
var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
   {
    Reference = new OpenApiReference {Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "bearer"}
   };

Comment: @Edd So you need two OpenApiSecurityScheme instances, not just one?  Should this just be added to your code, Brando Zhang?

Comment: @Brando Zhang, I'm confused; when I do all the above, including the part for Discovery, I still have to enter a Bearer token manually.  Does the setup for Discovery change the code above it?  Do I need to remove some of it?

Comment: I cannot get OpenID Connect Discovery to work after trying about a hundred different combinations of the above.  Any chance you can post a more complete example, without the "omitted for brevity", with all the code needed?  I cannot find any other documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Further asking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72187874/how-do-i-set-up-swashbuckle-and-swagger-ui-to-authorize-using-open-id-connect-di